# iOS segue from modal to non-modal

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I have a log in with email modal and from there I want to segue to the home screen non-modally.

Currently the flow works but is presenting the home screen modally. How would I present it normally?

from modal screen upon successful log in:

```
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tabBarController")

//                self.present(vc, animated: true) //works but modally
                  self.show(vc, sender: self)  //works but modally
```

Comment: What do you mean "present it normally"? Do you want back navigation?

Comment: No, just non-modally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tabBarController")
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```